# Deploying React App to Git Hub Pages giving error

Tags: reactjs, git, npm

I tried to follow a reactJs tutorial, but it shows an error while deploying the code on Github pages. I tried to look for solutions but nothing is working. I am new to git and github so kindly help me with this error:

```
> my-first-app@0.1.0 deploy D:\Full Stack CWH\React Js\my-first-app
> gh-pages -d build

events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:280:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn git',
  path: 'git',
  spawnargs: [ 'config', 'user.name' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-first-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-first-app@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\agarw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-25T15_49_32_003Z-debug.log
PS D:\Full Stack CWH\React Js\my-first-app>
```

Comment: `Error: spawn git ENOENT` suggests that Git isn't installed. Is it? If so, does npm have the right location for it?

Answer (score 0):

Delete you package node_modules on you AppData/Roaming, re install.

Comment: I didnt find any node_module in appdata/roaming but i reinstalled node modules in my project folder still it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

It just somehow didn't give the error the next day after I restarted my pc maybe restarting just fixed my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).